# How to update a M2M field in django via AJAX call

Tags: ajax, django, many-to-many, manyrelatedmanager

I am building a user profile in django, where I want the user to enter his skill set. The skill field is a `ManyToMany` field to a model name `Skills`. Below is shown the `models.py` file

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True, null=True)


class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %(self.name)
```

As you can see all the fields are set `null=True`. This is because I am keeping the fields empty and want the user to input them as and when he/she wants to. So I am updating all these fields using AJAX call. I have managed to edit all the other fields, but I do not know how can I edit a `M2M field`

I can get a list of all the skills linked to a profile using `profile.skills.all()` but I do not know how to update this list. I basically want to add or remove skill objects from this list. I think there is something in the `django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager` using which I can edit the field

Any help is really appreciated. I have not found anything at all on this subject. There is some information about editing this field using a ModelForm but nothing about editing the individual field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit the m2m intermediary table, use the `add` and `remove` methods on the `ManyRelatedManager`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add

It's true, the hardest things to google on the django docs are manytomanyfield and other continuous strings. I've blogged about `formfield_for_manytomany` solely to appear in search results for myself.

Comment: I think I have wrongly phrased my question, I do not want to edit the skill objects themselves but I want to edit the M2M field in the profile model, by editing I mean I want to add or remove `skill` objects to my `profile.skills`

Comment: Oh, my mistake! `profile.skills.add(object_id)` and `profile.skills.remove(object_id)` will add and remove skills. You can filter them directly via `profile.skills.through` which is just another django model

Comment: I have not understood how I can filter them through `profile.skills.through` Can you please give me a link for that. Thanks alot for your help

Comment: You can filter directly from the `ManyRelatedManager`: `profile.skills.filter(foo=bar)` which is already constrained to the current model.